# Set temporary director for raster() in R not working

Tags: raster, r, parallel-processing

I have a large raster data set that I am trying to use Maxent to make predictions regarding habitat suitability. I have had trouble with speed, and so I rewrote my code to parallel process based on this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206822/speed-up-maxent-prediction-in-r).

```
ncores = 4
cl = parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl,ncores)
rows=1:nrow(env)
split=sort(rows%%ncores)+1
outname="envOut"
prediction = foreach(i=unique(split), .combine=c) %dopar% {
    rows_sub=rows[split==i]
    sub = raster::crop(env,raster::extent(env,min(rows_sub),max(rows_sub),1,ncol(env)))
    raster::predict(object=env, model = model1,
    filename=paste("I:/GIS/Projects/LISU/",outname,i,".tif",sep=""))
    gc()
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

However, when I did so, over 500 GB of hard drive space was used and I was unable to generate an output raster. I added the following line before my block of code based on these [posts](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2014-March/020745.html).

```
rasterOptions(tmpdir="I:/GIS/tmpdir")
```

The I drive is an external hard drive location that has a ton of space. However, the command seems to have been ignored, as when I reran the parallel prediction, my hard drive filled up again. Any advice?

Comment: I think this is probably better posed for StackOverflow -- doesn't have much to do with GIS _per se_. Also, it would be helpful to have a fully reproducible version of your example (even if it's at a much smaller scale than your actual problem)

Comment: I agree that it should be moved, but not sure how to do so.

Comment: Let me ping the moderators... if you're in a hurry, I'd just copy-paste the question there and delete this one (though that's generally not the recommended approach)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, I set my environmental variable `TMPDIR=I:\GIS\tmpdir.`

When I started R, typing `tempdir()` retrieved the correct path to the temporary directory that I wanted to use.

I am still not sure what `rasterOptions(tmpdir=...)` actually does.